# OpenGL the text moving with the camera and also the texture was also behaving the same way expert advise needed

Tags: c++, opengl, animation, glut

i am Making a pool game using openGL and finding this problem vary irritating.
while i am trying to print one text on the screen and move my camera the text is also leaving its original position in the window and moving with the camera.

here is the code that i have in draw().

```
void display() {
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);          // Clear Screen and Depth Buffer
    glLoadIdentity();
    // GLfloat position1[] = { 00.0, 100.0, 00.0, 1.0 };

    //cam position update
    gluLookAt( world.camera->cameraFrom.x,world.camera->cameraFrom.y,world.camera->cameraFrom.z, world.camera->cameraTo.x,0,world.camera->cameraTo.z, 0,1,0);    // Define a viewing transformation
                                      // Pop the current matrix stack

    //**************************************************************
    drawTable(world.table);     
    world.update();

    glPushMatrix();
     sprintf(str, "Player 1 Score: 1, Player 2 Score: 10");
     glRasterPos2f(10, 10);
     glutBitmapString(font,(unsigned char*)str);
    glPopMatrix();
    glutSwapBuffers();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

`glRasterPos()` transforms the given position by the modelview and projection matrices.  You'll have to reset those to something that positions your text correctly:

```
void display() 
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    // set projection matrix here

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    //cam position update
    gluLookAt
        ( 
        world.camera->cameraFrom.x, world.camera->cameraFrom.y, world.camera->cameraFrom.z, 
        world.camera->cameraTo.x, 0, world.camera->cameraTo.z, 
        0,1,0
        );

    drawTable(world.table);     
    world.update();


    glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
    glLoadIdentity();
    // set appropriate projection matrix here

    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
    glLoadIdentity();

    sprintf(str, "Player 1 Score: 1, Player 2 Score: 10");
    glRasterPos2f(10, 10);
    glutBitmapString(font,(unsigned char*)str);

    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

Or use `glWindowPos2f()` instead, which bypasses both matrices and sets the raster position directly.

Comment: Thank you for your advise.this is also not working .. what can i do `void display() {
 glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);       // Clear Screen and Depth Buffer
 glLoadIdentity();
 glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
  
 glPushMatrix();
  sprintf(str, "Player 1 Score: 1, Player 2 Score: 10");
     glRasterPos2f(0, 0);
     glutBitmapString(font,(unsigned char*)str);
 glPopMatrix();
 

 glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
 glLoadIdentity();
 gluLookAt( world.camera->cameraFrom.x,world.camera->cameraFrom.y,world.camera->cameraFrom.z, world.camera->cameraTo.x,0,world.camera->cameraTo.z, 0,1,0);